# Setting /SECURITYMODE to Mixed Mode For SQL Server 2012 Install

Tags: installation, command-line-arguments, sql-server-2012

I'm installing SQL Server 2012 from the command line as part of an installer I'm creating.

I want to use mixed security (eg to allow both SQL and Windows authentication).

From looking at the [Microsoft install guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx) I can see that setting `/SECURITYMODE` to `SQL`, and `/SAPWD` to a password, will give SQL mode, and by not setting them, I can get the default (Windows Authentication).

But how do I specify that I want to use mixed mode at the command line?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After testing this, I've found that setting /SECURITYMODE to SQL installs SQL Server in mixed mode; and not setting the flag sets Windows Authentication only mode. There is no SQL only authentication mode.

Comment: Also make sure that comply with the following. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/965823

Comment: The documentation should clearly state this, but it doesn't https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt?view=sql-server-2017